# Bulk Export of Cassandra column family to CSV

Tags: csv, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, nosql

How does one export a 50 GB column family from Cassandra to a CSV file? I have explored:

1.) Copy ... To - this results in an rpc_timeout

2.) Have cassandra output the results of a query directly to a text a file - results in rpc_timeout

I have manipulated the read and write request timeout values (restarting dse everytime) in the cassandra.yaml file with no success. How do you export this data to CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Brian Hess's cassandra unloader. Its probably the most user friendly and performant tool out there.

https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/loader/CqlDelimUnload.java

It might become part of the core project.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CASSANDRA-9048

Comment: Does the tool work with an arbitrary number of columns aka wide column families?  It looks like you need to specify the exact columns in the schema parameter.

Comment: Yes. Remember that based on your partition key, cql rows can be written as wide rows within a single partition. You always need to specify exact columns when creating a cql table. Cassandra is not schemaless